# Error in Composer install using Wamp and Windows 7

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, package

I tried to update my composer to install new packages and got this

the APPDATA or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be  set up for composer to run correctly

cant seem to find anything on it in google or the IRC

Comment: with command do you use?

Comment: composer self-update

Comment: do you have an APPDATA environment variable set??

Comment: I dont know where it should be defined.

Comment: I used the windows version of composer (an exe I figured it would do this automatically)

Comment: im using laravel as well not sure if that helps.

Comment: the reason you are getting this message is because Windows doesn't know where your composer is installed in order to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cmd prompt.

```
SET COMPOSER_HOME="C:\path\to\composer"
composer self-update
```

[This article](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm) shows you how to set an environment variable to always be available.

Comment: Thanks a ton bud! lol you saved my life! id vote it up but Im not level 15. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Laragon, a modern **isolated** WAMP to avoid seeing errors like that.
Laragon bundles composer, Memcached, Redis, it has many useful features over WAMP and fully supports Laravel.
To run composer, just open Laragon's Shell and type composer

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is missing for few of the windows user.

What you can do is define the APPDATA env var yourself, it should point to C:\Users*YOUR USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming on vista/7 (and I guess win8)

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2033